# What type to use for JSON: string or xstring?

Tags: json, string, hex, transformation, abap

I create JSON with ABAP methods.

For example:

```
DATA(lo_json_writer) = cl_sxml_string_writer=>create( type = if_sxml=>co_xt_json ).
CALL TRANSFORMATION id
        SOURCE result = result
        RESULT XML lo_json_writer.

cl_abap_conv_in_ce=>create( )->convert(
        EXPORTING
          input = lo_json_writer->get_output( )
        IMPORTING
          data = json ).
```

Which data type should I use for json?

Use `string` or `xstring`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no "good way". Each solution has advantages and drawbacks.

If your data contains mostly "latin" characters, then use `xstring` with UTF-8 encoding, it will occupy less memory.

- `xstring` with UTF-8 encoding: one byte for common A-Z/a-z/0-9 characters, two bytes for accentuated characters, and more bytes for characters from other languages (Chinese and so on).
- `string`: two bytes per character (encoding is like `UCS-2`), since all ABAP systems are now Unicode (ABAP >= 7.50).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to distinguish between Unicode and UTF. Unicode is high level thing. Unicode does not know "bytes". The number of bytes per character are handled in the unicode transfer format (or in this context unicode storage format).

Answer (score 2):

According to this blog-entry(https://blogs.sap.com/2013/01/07/abap-and-json/): "For storing XML data in strings or internal tables, we recommend that you use byte strings or byte-like line types"  Therefore i would use xstring.